# Cannot configure connection to Azure Repo for Jenkins Job

Tags: azure, jenkins

Configured an Azure Repository with files from a repo in Gitlab. After creating the repo, I tried creating a Jenkins job trying to link it to the repo in Azure but getting an error which is status code 128.

To resolve the issue, I logged into the Jenkins Master Machine (Windows OS) and downloaded Putty Gen. I added the SSH key to my account in Azure and still cannot get the jenkins job connect to the repo in Azure.

Can someone please suggest on how could I tackle this error. Usually when I've done clones before, cloning just works by putting the https address in. Looks like that might not work as the organization is huge and uses active directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I followed the steps from this document:- [Configuring a CD pipeline for your Jenkins CI | Azure DevOps Hands-on-Labs (azuredevopslabs.com)](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/jenkins/)
> to add Azure DevOps repository to the Jenkins and it was cloned successfully like below:-

I created one sample Maven Job by following the steps in the document above, Refer below:-

[image]

I **installed Git plugin in Jenkins** like below:-

Click on **Manage Jenkins**:-

[image]

Then ***select Manage Plugins > Available Plugins > Search Git > Install without restart*** :-

[image]

I already have Git Plugin installed, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

Now, I selected my ***maven project > Source Code management > Git option was visible > If you do not see Git option in Source code management, Make sure you have installed the above Git Plugin properly> enter your repository URL > If your Azure DevOps repository is Private, Click on Generate Credentials > And add the Username and Password in your Jenkins Credentials like below***:-

**My Azure DevOps repository:-**

***Select your Azure DevOps Repos > Select the repository you want to clone> Select Clone > And Generate credentials > Copy the Username and Password*** :-

[image]

***If you do not add above Username and Password in your Jenkins Credentials***, You will ***receive an error like below***:-

[image]

To resolve this error and Add credentials > ***Click on Add Jenkins> And add the username and password*** like below:-

[image]

***Add Username and Password here from your Azure DevOps repo generated credentials:-***

[image]

***In the credentials select the newly added credentials instead of None***> And the Azure DevOps repository is cloned successfully like below:-

[image]

Now add your Build Pre and Post steps and check your build.
In order to run Azure DevOps jobs make sure you add
**VS Team Services Continuous Deployment** in the Jenkins Plugin to run CI/CD jobs.